# How may I disable giant tooltips on cursor hover?

Tags: macos, tooltip

All of a sudden, I’m seeing giant tooltips on cursor hover over any item in any program on my MacBook Pro. I’ve not changed any settings lately, nor have I installed new software. I can’t seem to find any guidance to fix this, and it’s interfering with every bit of work I do, as the pop-up boxes obscure text that I need to see to make selections. In other words, useless tooltips are hiding menu selections and driving me nuts. My first thought was that there was an accessibility setting causing this, but I don’t see a setting that I can disable. Any guidance you can offer would be greatly appreciated!

[giant tooltip obscures everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkNA5.jpg)

Comment: http://askdifferent.com may have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

[image: deselect Enable Hover Text]
<sup>**uncheck Enable Hover Text**</sup>

Comment: Please explain your answer in sentences. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.